# Stored procedures doesn't execute when stopping Java

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, stored-procedures, eclipselink

I created a stored procedure in MySQL and called it from a Java application with JPA EclipseLink. Once the procedure is called, it has a "sleep(sec)" method inside, and then it executes something successfully unless the application is turned off, it seems like the procedure is canceled too which is not what I want. The same thing I tried using JDBC PreparedStatements, the same result. Is there any workaround to make the stored procedure work even if the app was shut down after the procedure call.

**Stored Procedure**

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS session_procedure//
CREATE PROCEDURE session_procedure
(
IN userID INT
)
BEGIN
SELECT SLEEP(30);
UPDATE users 
SET users.Active = 0 
WHERE users.Id = userID;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Procedure call in Java**

```
public static void destroySessionCountdown(EntityManager entityManager, Account akk){
        int accountId = akk.getId();

        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("session_procedure");
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.setParameter(1, accountId);

        try {
            storedProcedure.execute();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // force logout
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean canceled?  More information is needed,

Comment: Note: there is quite a bit of speculation on my part. Without further information, I would suspect the stored procedure to be executed in a transaction opened by JPA. Thus, if the Java process terminates before the procedure has successfully executed, the transaction has to be rolled back to guarantee atomicity. I am not sure, however, if it is possible to influence/configure this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that when you closed connection to the DB, all processes related to it were cancelled including the running call of this stored procedure. I don't think you can avoid it.

What you are trying to implement is a kind of scheduled job. I would suggest to use *cron* instead. For the procedure you shown a simple SQL instead of stored procedure would be sufficient. The logic related to delays and to the execution time could be placed to a shell script and to the *cron*.

Comment: Found a workaround. Replaced the stored procedure with an Event and triggered it in a Transaction.